# Bootstrap 4 center items inside card and list group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm new to Bootstrap and coding. I want to know how can I center all the list items below? (Including card tittle). I did some research on Stackoverflow before asking this, but couldn't make it work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Featured</div>
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush"> <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>MongoDB</strong>: NoSQL database</a>
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>Angular</strong>: JavaScript framework </a>
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>Express</strong>: Framework for Node</a>
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>Node.js</strong>: JavaScript environment</a>
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>ES2015</strong>: Latest version of JavaScript</a>
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>Babel</strong>: JavaScript compiler</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried applying CSS?

Comment: I tried aligning with text-center and align-items-center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

  <div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-header">
      Featured
    </div>
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush"> <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>MongoDB</strong>: NoSQL database</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>Angular</strong>: JavaScript framework </a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>Express</strong>: Framework for Node</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>Node.js</strong>: JavaScript environment</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>ES2015</strong>: Latest version of JavaScript</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>Babel</strong>: JavaScript compiler</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for it:

```
<style>
.list-group-item,.card-header {
        margin: 0 auto; /* Added */
       /* Added */
}

</style>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="card ">
          <div class="card-header">Featured</div>
          <div class="list-group list-group-flush"> <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>MongoDB</strong>: NoSQL database</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>Angular</strong>: JavaScript framework </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>Express</strong>: Framework for Node</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>Node.js</strong>: JavaScript environment</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>ES2015</strong>: Latest version of JavaScript</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>Babel</strong>: JavaScript compiler</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

you can check fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ms3d25jt/

Comment: Thanks for answering. :)

Comment: @Amy Rutledge  if you liked it you can give it a green tick and an  upvote  after all its your post